# How to convert FFmepg AVFrame to Gdiplus::Bitmap?

Tags: c++, bitmap, ffmpeg, gdi+, gdi

Guys, I process the video by FFmpeg, now I want to Convert the AVFrame to Gdiplus::Bitmap, then do something else, The Frame is 24bit RGB. But sometimes it failed

This is my code:

```
int ProcessFrame(AVFrame* src, const int margin_left, const int margin_top, const int margin_right, const int margin_bottom)
{

    // Start Gidplus
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    int stride = src->width * 3;

    // Load the image
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(src->width, src->height, stride, PixelFormat24bppRGB, src->data[0]);
    Gdiplus::Rect imageRect(margin_left, margin_top, bitmap->GetWidth() - margin_left - margin_right, bitmap->GetHeight() - margin_top - margin_bottom);
    Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
    bitmap->LockBits(&imageRect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat24bppRGB, &bitmapData);

    //Do something else

    bitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);

    // Delete bitmap
    delete bitmap;

    // Shut down Gdiplus
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

I found that the Bitmap has a method

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream();
```

So maybe we can convert the AVFrame to Stream firstly

Or the better way?

Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: Does it fail only sometimes, or all the time? What happens when it fail?